# Submit form always trigger the "remember password"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect, query-string, form-submit

Im having a language selector on my asp.net web site. I plan to do a submit when the visitor change langauge, like this:

> ```
> $('select#front_language').bind('change keyup', function () {
>     $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'languageaction').attr('value', 'change').appendTo('body');
>     $('form').submit();
> });
> ```

The problem is that I also have a login box (username/password) on the site. The above approch, in FF for example, will ask the user if he wish to remember password.

I also thought about doing a javascript redirect, but would then have to manipulate the querystring (ie ?language=enu should become ?language=jpn).

As it is not allowed to have multi forms on asp.net sites I am not sure how the best approach would be, any suggestions?

Comment: is this a client side message asking about the "remember password" option?

Comment: @Tim B James yes, this is a feature build into Firefox. Other browsers have something similar

Comment: A way to do it is to remove the password field before submit: $('#login_password').remove();

Comment: Can you try adding `autocomplete="off"` to the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I came up with this solution:

```
$('select#front_language').bind('change keyup', function () {
  $('#login_password').prop("autocomplete", "off");
  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'languageaction').attr('value', 'change').appendTo('body');
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Thank you for leading me in the right direction.